# Find values by specific key in a deep nested object

Tags: javascript, recursion, nested-loops

How would I find some values by specific key in a deep nested object?

For example, I have a data object and some allowed ids. I have a search function but it just return all ids and values.

```js
// data
let routers = {
  "1": {
    "menuid": 1,
    "title": "1",
    "children": {
      "2": {
        "menuid": 2,
        "title": "2",
        "children": {
          "3": {
            "menuid": 3,
            "title": "3",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "4": {
    "menuid": 4,
    "title": "4",
    "children": {
      "5": {
        "menuid": 5,
        "title": "5",
      }
    }
  },
  "20": {
    "menuid": 20,
    "title": "20",
    "children": []
  },
}

// Allow ids
const allowed = ['1', '2', '4', '20'];

// Filter
const filtered = (allowed, routers) => {
  return Object.keys(routers)
    .filter(key => allowed.includes(key))
    .reduce((obj, key) => {
      return {
        ...obj,
        [key]: routers[key],
        children: filtered(allowed, routers[key].children)
      };
    }, {})
};
  
console.log(filtered(allowed, routers));
```

So from the obj, I would like to produce an array with only the allowed IDs like this:

```
let routers = {
  "1": {
    "menuid": 1,
    "title": "1",
    "children": {
      "2": {
        "menuid": 2,
        "title": "2",
        "children": []
      }
    }
  },
  "4": {
    "menuid": 4,
    "title": "4",
    "children": []
  },
  "20": {
    "menuid": 20,
    "title": "20",
    "children": []
  },
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `[key]: routers[key],` will make a shallow copy of the value, so you get everything. Then it adds a *children* property to the accumulator, not to `routers[key]`, so its value is replaced every time. Since the last property doesn't have any children, in the last iteration *children* is assigned an empty object. You need to iterate over each property and only do recursion when you hit a *children* property.

Comment: Deepdash can be a nice solution to some deeply nested challenges.

Answer (score 0):

We can go over each key-value pair in the given `routers` object. When we see that the key is in the `allowed` array`we check its`children`, else we delete that entry.

We do this recursively:

```js
 function searchIds(arr, data) {
  Object.entries(data).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if(arr.includes(k)){
      if(v.children && !Array.isArray(v.children)){
        searchIds(arr, v.children);
        if(v.children && !Array.isArray(v.children) && Object.keys(v.children).length === 0){
          v.children = [];
        }
      }
    }else{
      delete data[k];
    }
  });
 };
const routers = {
      "1": {
        "menuid": 1,
        "title": "1",
        "children": {
          "2": {
            "menuid": 2,
            "title": "2",
            "children": {
              "3": {
                "menuid": 3,
                "title": "3",
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "4": {
        "menuid": 4,
        "title": "4",
        "children": {
          "5": {
            "menuid": 5,
            "title": "5",        
          }
        }
      },
      "20": {
        "menuid": 20,
        "title": "20",
        "children": []
     },
 };
const allowed = ['1', '2', '4', '20'];
searchIds(allowed, routers)
console.log(routers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```js
const filtered = (allowed, routers) => {
  if (routers) {
    const result = Object.keys(routers)
      .filter(key => allowed.includes(key))
      .reduce((result, key) => Object.assign(result, { [key]: {
        ...routers[key],
        children: filtered(allowed, routers[key].children)
      }}), {});
    if (Object.keys(result).length > 0) {
      return result;
    }
  }
  return [];
};

let routers = {
  "1": {
    "menuid": 1,
    "title": "1",
    "children": {
      "2": {
        "menuid": 2,
        "title": "2",
        "children": {
          "3": {
            "menuid": 3,
            "title": "3",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "4": {
    "menuid": 4,
    "title": "4",
    "children": {
      "5": {
        "menuid": 5,
        "title": "5",
      }
    }
  },
  "20": {
    "menuid": 20,
    "title": "20",
    "children": []
  },
}

const allowed = ['1', '2', '4', '20'];
  
console.log(filtered(allowed, routers));
```

On a side note: you'd better stick to using objects everywhere for consistency. So I recommend you use empty objects instead of empty arrays. If you do, you won't need the if statement on the line 9.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good practice not to modify the original data.  So my solution creates a copy with `reduce()` while filtering.

In case you change the structure of the object in the future, I put other allowed keys such as `menuid`, `title`, `children` in the allowed list internally.  I think this way is extendable and safer for future change.

I also modified the data of which last element of `children` to an object.  It was an array.  If you want to mix arrays and object, let me know, I will modify the code for you.  Just one more conditional statement needs to be added in the recursive function `_filter()` to handle an array.

```
const filtered = (allowed, routers) => {
  const allowList = [...allowed, "menuid", "title", "children"];
  const _filter = (obj) => {
    if (typeof obj !== "object" || obj === null)
      return obj;
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((accum, key) => {
      if (allowList.includes(key)) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj[key] !== null)
          accum[key] = _filter(obj[key]);
        else
          accum[key] = obj[key];
      }
      return accum;
    }, {});
  };
  return _filter(routers);
};
```

Here is the complete code to run and test.

```js
// data
const routers = {
  "1": {
    "menuid": 1,
    "title": "1",
    "children": {
      "2": {
        "menuid": 2,
        "title": "2",
        "children": {
          "3": {
            "menuid": 3,
            "title": "3",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "4": {
    "menuid": 4,
    "title": "4",
    "children": {
      "5": {
        "menuid": 5,
        "title": "5",
      }
    }
  },
  "20": {
    "menuid": 20,
    "title": "20",
    "children": {}
  },
}

// Allow ids
const allowed = ['1', '2', '4', '20'];

// Filter
const filtered = (allowed, routers) => {
  const allowList = [...allowed, "menuid", "title", "children"];
  const _filter = (obj) => {
    if (typeof obj !== "object" || obj === null)
      return obj;
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((accum, key) => {
      if (allowList.includes(key)) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj[key] !== null)
          accum[key] = _filter(obj[key]);
        else
          accum[key] = obj[key];
      }
      return accum;
    }, {});
  };
  return _filter(routers);
};

console.log(filtered(allowed, routers));
```

Answer (score 0):

i am just using recursive method, you can try this code.

```js
let routers = {
      "1": {
        "menuid": 1,
        "title": "1",
        "children": {
          "2": {
            "menuid": 2,
            "title": "2",
            "children": {
              "3": {
                "menuid": 3,
                "title": "3",
                "children": []
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "4": {
        "menuid": 4,
        "title": "4",
        "children": {
          "5": {
            "menuid": 5,
            "title": "5",        
          }
        }
      },
      "20": {
        "menuid": 20,
        "title": "20",
        "children": []
      },
    }
    
const allowed = ['1','2','4','20'];
const filtered = (routes, allowed) => {
    if( Object.keys(routes).length === 0 && routes.constructor === Object ) {
    return {};
  } else {
    let temp = {}
    for(index in routes) {
            let route = routes[index];
        if (allowed.includes(index)){
        temp[route.menuid] = {
          'menuid':route.menuid,
          'title': route.title,
          'children': filtered(route.children, allowed)
        }
      }             
    }
    return temp
  }
}

console.log(filtered(routers, allowed))
```